How to avoid boilerplate code in static classes?
I have the following code:
public static class ScriptingSymbolDefiner_JSON_DOT_NET
{
    //different for every definer class
    private const string Symbol = "JSON_DOT_NET";
    private static List<NamedBuildTarget> buildTargets = new()
    {
        NamedBuildTarget.Android, NamedBuildTarget.iOS, NamedBuildTarget.NintendoSwitch, NamedBuildTarget.Server,
        NamedBuildTarget.Standalone
    };
    
    //from here on all code will be the same for every definer class
    private const string MenuName = "Wichtel/Scripting Symbols/" + Symbol;
    private const string SettingName = "EnableScriptingSymbol_" + Symbol;

    public static bool IsEnabled
    {
        get => EditorPrefs.GetBool(SettingName, false);
        set => EditorPrefs.SetBool(SettingName, value);
    }

    [MenuItem(MenuName)]
    private static void ToggleAction()
    {
        IsEnabled = !IsEnabled;
        SymbolDefinerUtilities.UpdateSymbolDefinition(Symbol, IsEnabled, buildTargets);
    }

    [MenuItem(MenuName, true)]
    private static bool ToggleActionValidate()
    {
        Menu.SetChecked(MenuName, IsEnabled);
        return true;
    }
}

The idea is that there will be multiple classes like the one provided. The only difference will be the values of Symbol and buildTargets. The classes need to be static because that's a requirement of Unity when using the [MenuItem()] attribute.
Is there a possibility to make this more elegant with less boilerplate? An abstract base class doesn't work for static classes.

"The classes need to be static because otherwise Unity complains" - Then that's the actual problem you should be trying to solve.

Sorry,  maybe I framed that sentence weirdly. It's a requirement from Unity that a method with the [MenuItem()] attribute is static.

Ah, different story, then. Now I am thinking "Composition over Inheritance" - can you rip out the "Boilerplate" into a separate non-static class that your static MenuItem - classes have a "has-a" relation to?

Hmm, not as easy as I thought at first ... I am starting to think "Source Generator" ...

Yea, I think it's just not possible in C# because mixins are not a thing. Maybe it's possible with default interface implementations? Source Generator would be overkill in my case, tbh. I just thought I'd miss something obvious.

I just messed around in dotnetfiddle with default interface impl, but didn't get it to work as intended, neither. That's why I drifted towards SG...

Static interface members would also require C# 11, which is not supported by Unity (yet). I guess there is no sensible way around Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V.

You should try T4 templates. Source generation might not be as hard as you think.

^^ Yes, it's actually kind of fun - once you get them to work.

"The classes need to be static because that's a requirement of Unity" -> Not really. You can use an abstract class, but the question is how much are you willing to keep writing? There is still a need to "manually" write the constants (the Symbol name and the MenuName). While the target platforms need not be constant, even if you pass them as params to the base class, you'd still need to write them down. For example, a small test I did barely reduced the code and still needs copy-pasting for multiple symbol classes even if I could take advantage of inheritance.

In a small PoC I did based on your case, I reduced the 2 menu items from 2 lines of code each to 1 line of code each (the base call). I could get rid of the IsEnabled property and that's kinda it. Ideally, you'd want the power of the evil C++ preprocessor macros or the C++23 templates. Neither which is available in C#.

The only way to reduce writing code is having a file as you do, to server as text template (I don't mean C# generic) and then execute a commandline with params for the constants which would create a new file from the template and replace the markers with the params you passed. Or, of course, write it as an Editor utility accessible from the main menu or the context menu that asks for those constants in an editor window (so basically, a sort of "New C# Script" but, in your case, "New Scripting Define Handler"). Which is kinda what Unity does when you create a new C# script from the Editor.
